# Formula record in Crystal Reports not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm using VB.NET 2010 with Crystal Reports 13_0_10, and I'm getting an error in setting a parameter in Crystal Reports: the result doesn't filter by my formula.

I create parameter field (number) called id then make formula record:

```
{Attechment_AB.attid} = {?id}
```

then in VB.NET pass value to Crystal Reports by

```
rpt.SetParameterValue("id", txtId.Text)
```

When I used VB.NET 2008 the code worked correctly, but now it displays all the values of the table.

Comment: where did you write the formula in crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter the data according to some parameter then you need to write the formula in `Record Selection Formula` and not in formula editor.

You can get the record selection formula from `Report -> selection formula --> record selection formula` tab in crystal report.

Comment: i do that , but same resutl

Comment: Have you checked the query? Fire the same on database and check result